# multiplying each value in one vector to all values in a second vector and creating a results matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have two vectors:

```
 x <- c(5,10,15,20,25)
 y <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

I want to multiply each element in x by all the values in y and create a matrix so I have the x1 - x5 as rows and y1 - y10 as columns and the multiplied value in each cell.

so ...

```
     y1      y2     y3  ...  y10
x1  x1y1    x1y2   x1y3     x1y10
x2  x2y1    x2y2   x2y3     x2y10
x3  x3y1    x3y2   x3y3     x3y10
x4  x4y1    x4y2   x4y3     x4y10
x5  x5y1    x5y2   x5y3     x5y10
```

Or with the values..

```
    y1    y2    y3  ... y10
x1  50    100   150     500
x2  100   200   300     1000 
x3  150   300   450     1500
x4  200   400   600     2000
x5  250   500   750     2500
```

I know how I would do this in for loops, but is there a way to do this in apply statements?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `outer(x, y)` or `x %o% y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `outer`.

```
outer(x, y, FUN = "*")
```

If you want to use plus instead of multiplication you can change `*` to ·+·

```
outer(x, y, FUN = "+")
```